# While trying "container.projects.locations.clusters.get" kubernetes API in GCP API Explorer for GKE am getting '500 Internal Server Error'

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, google-apis-explorer

While trying  "container.projects.locations.clusters.get" GCP API Explorer web consoleam getting '500 Internal Server Error' what would be the reason help me to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

I did use the [**Method: projects.locations.clusters.get**](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.locations.clusters/get?apix_params=%7B%22name%22%3A%22projects%2Falarbi-dev%2Flocations%2Fus-central1-b%2Fclusters%2Floadbalancedcluster%22%7D) and I did get "200" response with all my cluster informations.
One field is required to do is the **"name"** field and the expression should be like below:

> projects/**your project ID**/locations/**your cluster zone**/clusters/**your cluster name**

you can use as well a python script to run the same thing

```
"""
from pprint import pprint

from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()

service = discovery.build('container', 'v1', credentials=credentials)

# The name (project, location, cluster) of the cluster to retrieve.
# Specified in the format 'projects/*/locations/*/clusters/*'.
name = 'projects/<your project ID>/locations/<your cluster zone>/clusters/<your cluster name>'  # TODO: Update placeholder value.

request = service.projects().locations().clusters().get(name=name)
response = request.execute()

# TODO: Change code below to process the `response` dict:
pprint(response)
```

Make sure you install the module as below required for authentication:

```
sudo pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client

sudo pip install --upgrade oauth2client
```